# Calculate average of the temperature value from 4 surrounded points in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, interpolation

There are two-point tables. One includes *temperature value* and the other does not have this information. I would like to calculate the average of the temperature for the 2nd table based on the four closest points around the first ones. I wonder how can I do it in PostGIS.

Comment: cross join lateral on the 2 tables -- in the lateral subquery find the 4 closest points and only return the temperature values to the outer query

Comment: @ziggy could you please provide the sample code since I am new in post gis, so it is difficult for me to implement the theory :)

Comment: do you need the average of the 4 closest points?

Comment: @ziggy Yes, I need the avg.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this should do the trick -- just replace your tables and columns where needed

```
SELECT a.id,
       a.geom,
       avg(c.temp_val) temp_val
FROM tablea a
CROSS JOIN lateral
  (SELECT temp_val
   FROM tableb b
   ORDER BY b.geom <-> a.geom
   LIMIT 4)c
GROUP BY a.id,a.geom
```

the idea is to take table a (outer table) 1 record at a time and find the 4 closest points for that record in the cross join subquery. the cross join lateral is bit tricky to explain but in a way it kind of functions like a for loop. for a better explanation on lateral refer to the answer in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-lateral-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql

Comment: if I want to calculate the weighted average based on the distance what theoretically do then?

Comment: not exactly sure I know what you're asking but i'd probably ask another question

Comment: I would also recommend editing your question to include that you want the average. seems like some people want to close your question. normally the questioner shows some attempt with code but your question seemed clear enough for me...